# How to test if selector exists in CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I know I can use:

```
casper.test.assertExists(#selector);
```

But I want to actually store if it exists in a boolean variable.

I.e. something like this:

```
var exists = SelectorExists(#selector);
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I just found out:

```
if(!casper.exists('#selector')){
   #selector doesn't exist
}
```